# Store input from a text field in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, input

I'm fairly new to this, but I'm trying to costumize a plugin called democracy_poll for wordpress. It's a poll form where you can add your own answer. The answers get stored in the database, and what I need is to make the email input field I have created to output its value together with the answer (so I can contact the winner)

So like I said I have added an Email input field and would like to store the users input in a variable so I can see the input user email together with the answer they gave in the database.

I have added a new column in the database called author and added 'author' at the end of this code in the php file:

```
$exists = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT aid FROM $wpdb->democracy_a " .
        "WHERE answer = '%s' AND qid = $this->id",
        $new_answer
    )
);

if (!$exists)
    if (
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->democracy_a,
            array(
                'qid'      => $this->id,
                'answer'   => $new_answer,
                'votes'    => 0,
                'added_by' => 1,
                'author'   => $author
            )
        )
    )
```

with this, if

```
$author = "hello@email.com"
```

`hello@email.com` appears in the new column in the database next to the users answer.

So I'm wonder how to get the value from my email input box and store it in a php variable that I can use here?

My best guess so far has been $_POST["name"] but no luck :(

Thanks in advance!

W

Comment: what is the actual value for the name attribute in the HTML, on your new input tag?

Comment: Can you show the code for POST? Although your "guess" for getting the post data field is right.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code of your HTML.

But, if you are using the value "name" in name attribute such as `<input type="text" name="name">` then your `$_POST["name"]` will not work as "name" is a reserved name (or variable) for WP internal usage.

I suggest you to replace value in name attribute with something else like `<input type="text" name="nameUnique">` and give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! We finally figured it out.

We had to define the variable for the email input in an ajax function,
then run a preg_match in the php file that handled the ajax data, against all the variables in the array to get the email address.

As I said I'm still new at this and it's very difficult for me to give you a detailed answer to my own question even though it was just solved.

I hope to keep learning and be able to contribute more in the future,
thanks again!!

W